# PDF for ubuntu server and solaris server commandline

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, solaris, ubuntu-10.04

please if anyone have a "pdf" contain a full list of ubunt(server) commandline with detail and other one for sun solaris(server)

Comment: I'm thinking you really don't want the monster pdf, what is your goal?

Comment: my goal is collect a large number of command with your explain ... becuse i need just one referance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want PDF's of them, but you can check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/index.html#man-info) for all of the PDF's of the Solaris 10 man pages.  Sections 1 and 1M cover the provided command line utilities.

Answer (score 0):

[Using the Terminal - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

[Know Your Terminal Commands](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=990636)

and the [Ubuntu Cheat Sheet](http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/ubuntu-cheat-sheet/) (with the [pdf here](http://files.fosswire.com/2008/04/ubunturef.pdf))

[Solaris Advanced User's Guide PDF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/806-7612/806-7612.pdf)

Many of the commands are going to be the same between Linux and Solaris

Answer (score 0):

That would be a big pdf!

http://bhami.com/rosetta.html

Is very handy for figuring out how to do things on an unfamiliar Unix.

Install the gnu utilities on Solaris, then it will be mostly the same.

Answer (score -1):

cups server + cups-pdf might work for you